Is it possible to partition an Athena table using a variable which is timestamp datatype
I am trying to partition an athena table by a timestamp variable called 'forecast_datetime'. To use this variable as a partition I have made it 'string', with following values:
'2007-12-10-11-00-00', '2007-12-10-12-00-00', '2007-12-10-13-00-00', '2007-12-10-14-00-00', ... etc.
I can't figure this out. Thanks.

Sorry, but you haven't given enough details for us to be able to assist you. Can you show us what you tried and what happened? Any error messages? Please Edit your Question to add the additional details.

Yes you can.
But you should consider the most partition key suitable for your case (i mean, Does it really need to be that detailed?, that even seconds is included).
Because by using partition key, you can restrict the amount of data scanned by each query. Thus it can be improving performance and reducing cost.
Source: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/partitions.html
